# How to use AJAX-FORM with Polymer?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, polymer

I am trying to post some simple data with ajax on polymer but I am having some difficulty.

I am using https://github.com/rnicholus/ajax-form by rnicholus.

All my page has is an input and email that I am trying to store on the server.

Currently, all that happens after the button is submitted is it takes me to a blank page which reads 'Array()'. So the data isn't being passed through.

I can't figure this out and have been trying for a few days so any help is much appreciated!

Here is my code

HTML

```
  <div class="main" flex layout vertical cross-fade-delayed?="{{parentElement.lastSelected === 'splash'}}">
    <div class="card {{ {wide: wide} | tokenList }}" flex layout vertical slide-up-offscreen?="{{parentElement.selected === 'profile'}}" cross-fade="{{!wide && parentElement.selected !== 'profile'}}">
      <div layout vertical flex cross-fade-delayed?="{{parentElement.lastSelected !== 'splash' && wide}}" on-keypress="{{ keypressAction }}">
      <form is="ajax-form" action="/savejson.php" method="post" id="form-send">
        <div class="indent" layout vertical>
          <div class="header">{{userDefaults ? 'Your Profile' : 'Welcome'}}</div>
          <paper-input label="Name" name="first_name" id="first"></paper-input>
          <paper-input label="Email Address" name="email_address" id="last" maxlength="1"></paper-input>
        </div>
        <div horizontal center layout>
          <paper-button on-tap="{{handleLogout}}" hidden?="{{!user}}">Sign Out</paper-button>
          <!-- <button type="submit">Submit</button> -->
          <paper-fab id="check" icon="check" showing?="{{$.first.value.length && $.last.value.length && selectedAvatar !== undefined}}" on-tap="{{handleLogin}}" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"></paper-fab>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript

```
Polymer('ajax-form', {

  ajaxSend: function () {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
          alert('good');
        }
      }
    };  
    xhr.open('POST', 'savejson.php');
    xhr.send();

  }

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you unfamiliar with Polymer and web components in general. Your code suggests that you are trying to create your own ajax-form component, and not use the existing one (mine). The JavaScript in your above code is not needed. In fact, no JavaScript is required at all. Simple import ajax-form.html and use it in your markup.

Answer (score -1):

This element not released by polymer team you can use official form element iron-form https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form this will work on polymer version greater than or equal to 0.8

Comment: Sorry, which element isn't released yet?

Comment: It seems like the demo is using a 'get' instead of 'post', why is that?

How would I write the code for iron-form with my markup above?

Comment: Which version of polymer you are using?

Comment: The latest version. More specifically I am trying to create AJAX submissions with this demo https://github.com/polymer/topeka

so on the login screen, when the user enter's their first/last name it will store it on the server, or any of the quiz answers. 
But for now I am just trying to get the login to work

Comment: Post your full code i think you don't know how to work with polymer your JavaScript is totally incorrect this code will create a element of "ajax-form" in polymer but you don't need to create it i think you copied it from "ajax-form" source code. You need to download polymer and ajax-form and import both them in your html file and use ajax form in tag in html and in JavaScript you just need to add event listeners to form. Tell me if you don't know how to work with polymer?

Comment: First let me sure that you have installed polymer and import its script in main html file.